# strongly continuous mapping implies bounded mapping

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory

Hi does anyone know how to show the result that if we have a relexive Banach space $X$ and a mapping $A: X \rightarrow X^{*}$ (not necessarily linear), which is *strongly continuous*, which means  $$u_{n} \rightharpoonup u~~~\text{in }X\implies A(u_{n}) \rightarrow A(u)~~\text{ in }X^{*}$$ Then does it follow that $A$ is also bounded, in the sense that $A$ takes bounded sets to bounded sets?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @DavidMitra No it's necessarily linear. I changed it to 'mapping'.

Comment: @DavidMitra But does it follow trivially that if you have a bounded set $B$ in $X$ then $A(B)$ is bounded in $X^{*}$?

Comment: @DavidMitra Sorry! I meant it is NOT necessarily linear.

Comment: Ok, deleting comments...

Comment: What kind of convergence is understood for the $u_n$'s?

Comment: Suppose $(u_n)$ is bounded with $(Au_n)$ unbounded. Passing to a subsequence, if necessary, we may suppose $\Vert Au_n\Vert>n$. Use the fact that $(u_n)$ has a weakly convergent subsequence to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: @user161825 Convergence in weak topology for $\{u_{n}\}_{n}$ and convergence in strong topology for $\{A(u_{n})\}_{n}$.

Comment: As suggested by David Mitra above, I think you need to use that the weak topology corresponds to the weak star topology in the double dual, and then invoke Alaoglu's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for responses in the comments. Is this then okay?

*Proof:*
Assume there is some bounded set $B \subset X$, where $A(B)$ is unbounded in $X^{*}$. Then choose a sequence $\{ A(u_{n}) \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset A(B)$ such that $\| A(u_{n}) \| > n$. Note then that $\{ u_{n}\}_{n} \subset B$ is bounded in $X$, so by Kakutani's Theorem and Emerlein-Smulian Theorem it follows that there exists a subsequence $\{ u_{n_{k}} \}_{k}$ such that $u_{n_{k}} \rightharpoonup u$ in $X$. It follows then from the strong continuity assumption that $A(u_{n_{k}}) \rightarrow A(u)$, the sequence is therefore bounded. But we also have $\| A(u_{n_{k}}) \| \geq k$, which contradicts $\{ A(u_{n_{k}}) \}_{k}$ being bounded.

$\square$

Comment: $\| A(u_{n_k})\|\geq n_k$ with $n_k$ a strictly increasing sequence, but otherwise it looks correct.

Comment: Looks good!${}$